# How to get Flutter AlertDialog actions to watch for keyboard event (enter key)?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

Is there a way to get the "enter" key keyboard event in flutter to default to one of the action buttons on my AlertDialog?  Note I'm referring to use of flutter for web where there is a physical keyboard.  For example I have this dialog:

```
  Future<void> _confirmDelete(int index) async {
    var fp = SessionInfo.of(context).myFloorplans.entries.toList()[index].value;
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Confirm Delete?'),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Please confirm deleting ${fp.name}"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Delete'),
              onPressed: () {
                _deleteFloorplan(index);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to default the "enter" key on the keyboard to act like they hit delete?  Maybe not the safest UI experience yet, but mostly just asking to understand the foundation here.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: You could wrap the button in a `RawKeyboardListener` widget to listen for a key press and, if it's enter, perform the same action.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing you need to do is wrap your AlertDialog in a RawKeyboardListener.
check this example :

```
RawKeyboardListener(
// its better to initialize and dispose of the focus node only for this alert dialog 
  focusNode: FocusNode(),
  autofocus: true,
  onKey: (v) {
    if (v.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
      _deleteFloorplan(index);
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  },
  child: your alert dialog ...
```

Comment: This solution is buggy in my case but works the first time.

Comment: Much thanks! Also makes sense to add inside if `|| v.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.numpadEnter`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that will cause the keyboard to show in this dialog.

Anyway if you have a TextFormField that will show the keyboard you can do something like this

```
onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
            _deleteFloorplan(index);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
```

onFieldSubmitted gets called whenever the user hits the text Input action button (the "enter" key you mentioned)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified I use this app both on phones and web. So I was talking about if it was on a web browser.